# SSIS pkg does not recognize the file path

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, ssis, business-intelligence

I'm using the 2012 version of Visual Studio to build an SSIS package. I have a variable var_root which has the string value - 'C:\Projects\OBC\Clients\ABC'. When I try to run the pkg, I get the following error:

Error: The expression contains unrecognized token "C". If "C" is a variable, it should be expressed as "@C". The specified token is not valid. If the token is intended to be a variable name, it should be prefixed with the @ symbol.
Error: Attempt to parse the expression "C:\Projects\OBC\Clients\ABC" failed and returned error code 0xC00470A4. The expression cannot be parsed. It might contain invalid elements or it might not be well-formed. There may also be an out-of-memory error.

Now, this runs fine in the 2008 version of the Business Intelligence studio. I don't know how to specify the variable name. Please help me if possible. Thanks

Comment: I am guessing this package was migrated from the 2008 version. just set the path in the value column in your variable or set the expression as "C:\Projects\OBC\Clients\ABC" (with double quotes).

Comment: Yes, it worked!! I used double quotes and double slashes.."C:\\Projects\\OBC\\Clients\\ABC".

Comment: Oh forgot about the slashes but you would have got to it eventually.

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The SSIS expression language is a C based language and the \ is a token, this means you have to escape it with another one. i.e "\" becomes "\", unlike C# you can't prefix the string with a @, you have to use the escaping route.

In summary when ever you want to use \ you need to use two \

Answer (score 0):

Why use the expression though when you can set the value directly in the values column for the variable - without the quotes  or double slashes - Just - C:\Projects\OBC\Clients\ABC

[image]

Comment: I have a ForEach File Enumerator where I need to use that variable. I'm trying to copy several files to a db.

Comment: Yes but instead of using the expression .. if you scroll to the left you can set the value directly in the values column

Comment: U would not have had that feature in 2008 but is available in 2012.